# How do I integrate mSpec & ReSharper 7.0 in Visual Studio 11?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, mspec

I've been trying to get these beta programs to work together.  Resharper 7.0.3.261 runs just fine.  After a nuget install of machine.specifications, I run the InstallResharperRunner.7.0 - VS2011.bat file which copies the mspec dll and resharperRunner dll to the correct plugins folder in my profile.

Now, whenever I create a new project (Mvc 3 or 4) resharper load throws the following error:

> Initial instantiation of the component TypeComponent { MSpecUnitTestPresenter, State: Corrupted } has failed. Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. Could not load type 'JetBrains.ReSharper.Features.Common.TreePsiBrowser.TreeModelBrowserPresenter' from assembly 'JetBrains.ReSharper.Features.Common, Version=7.0.1.47, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1010a0d8d6380325'.

I've eliminated the possibility of corruption in the downloaded components by downloading several times, even compiling the mspec 7.0 runner and core dll from source. All variations result in the same error.

I know it's not reasonable to expect error free integration between beta projects - just wondering if someone else has run into this.  My objective is just to get mspec working in VS11, and the resharper runner seemed like a reasonable option.  Has anyone had success getting mspec to play nicely with VS11 Beta?

Comment: I haven't had the chance to install VS 11 and ReSharper 7 to test the runner with that version. Option 1) Please bear with me; option 2) try to recompile the 7.0 runner against the latest ReSharper binaries and see if that helps. Perhaps there are new things that need to be set up or new members to implement.

Comment: You are correct about the ReSharper 7 binaries.  After some tinkering I found that it works out of the box using the 7.0.0.325 ReSharper version. It also works well with TestDriven.net.

Comment: The steps I followed to get it working are: 1) Install Resharper 7.0.0.325 (Note as of this time there are several newer builds - that was the source of my problem).  2) Use nuget to install-package machine.specifications  3) As administrator Run the InstallResharperRunner.7.0 - VS2011.bat from your projects packages directory. 4) Go to your %AppData%/JetBrains/ReSharper/V7.0/vs11.0/Plugins directory and check properties of the four files and unblock them.

Comment: It appears that there were some significant breaking changes between JetBrains.ReSharper.Features.Common [7.0.0.325] and [7.0.3.261].  This problem is manifested in Presenter.cs where the JetBrains base class TreeModelBrowserPresenter no longer exists in [7.0.3.261].

Comment: Ok, so the changes weren't so significant. The TreeModelBrowserPresenter had just changed namespaces from JetBrains.ReSharper.Features.Common to JetBrains.ReSharper.Features.Shared.  MSpec runs just fine in VS11 Beta with ReSharper when compiled against current ReSharper binaries [7.0.3.261] with this change

Comment: Glad you were able to fix it. Can you please send me a pull request with your changes? I'll review and provide them to others who want to work with the cutting edge. :-)